# How to Query a Ordered Hash Table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, hashtable, aggregate-functions

I have a hash table (for tagging items) with an extra column for the strength of the relationship between items and their tags:

```
item_id | tag_name | relationship
1       | linux    | 0.7
1       | computer | 0.9
2       | garden   | 0.5
2       | shovel   | 0.65
...
```

I want to select all items tagged with both `'linux'` and `'computer'` (more tags are allowed), ordered by the sum of the relationships between items and these two tags.

Here's my attempt at querying the database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items
INNER JOIN (
SELECT items.id FROM items
    INNER JOIN tags ON items.id = tags.item_id
    GROUP BY tags.item_id
    HAVING ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_id) @> ARRAY['linux','computer']
    ORDER BY SUM(tags.relationship) DESC
) tagged_items ON items.id = tagged_items.id
```

For items that are **only** tagged with `'linux'` and `'computer'`, this works perfectly. But the problem is that for items that have additional tags, the `ORDER BY SUM(tags.relationship)` will sum over the other tags that an item has as well... in other words, items with the most tags will return first (and that's not what I want).

How can I make `SUM()` only sum over the relationships to the tags that I'm selecting?

Comment: Add `where tags.tag_id in ('linux', 'computer')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `in`:

```
select id
from items i
where tags_id in ('linux', 'computer')
group by id
order by sum(relationship) desc;
```

Unless you want all columns, then you can use the query above in cte and join:

```
with tmp as (
    select id
    from items
    where tags_id in ('linux', 'computer')
    group by id
    order by sum(relationship) desc
)
select i.*
from tmp t
inner join items i on t.id = i.id;
```